# Create AWS EC2 Security Group for Intercommunicating Redis

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I will be having Redis in a master-slave configuration where each Redis node is in a separate EC2 instance. Since each Redis slave will need to communicate with the master, I need to add the Redis' own security group ID as a source. However, I'm unsure as to what protocol Redis will be using. Should I set up the Security group rule as a Custom TCP with select access to ports, or should it just be the "All TCP" rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A custom tcp rule on port 6379 and the security group as source is enough